# Postgres Database connection pooling in django

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to implement database connection pooling in django.I have tried setting
"CONN_MAX_AGE" to None and even to a number like 1800 but this does not seem to help also I have tried setting

```
  DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": env("POSTGRES_DB"),
            "USER": env("POSTGRES_USER"),
            "PASSWORD": env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
            "HOST": env("POSTGRES_HOST"),
            "PORT": env("POSTGRES_PORT"),   
            'OPTIONS': {
                'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITTED,
                'conn_max_age': 600,
            },
        }
     }
```

but still I can't see database connections getting pooled.
I have another question how will I check if database connection is getting pooled or not?

tried above with no result

Comment: umm - why do you think django does connection pooling?

Comment: is not there any way I can do db connection pooling in django? @RichardHuxton

Comment: This is one case where Django decides not to be "batteries included". You'll need another library to pull this off. This one looks okay: https://github.com/altairbow/django-db-connection-pool (but do your own research)

Comment: You say both that it isn't being used, and that you don't know how to check if it is being used.  So then what makes you think it is not being used, if you don't know how to check?

Comment: @RichardHuxton the docs for CONN_MAX_AGE make be think that. It is not feature-rich, but it certainly seems to be the most important task of a pool.

Comment: If you make postgresql log connections and disconnections, then you can check how many of them there are compared to how many you would expect.